# Save lines of txt file into csv

Tags: pandas, csv, notepad

I have a txt file that looks like this

```
a,b,c
0,0,0
0,0,0
*
x,y,z
1,1,1
1,1,1
*
u,v,w
9,9,9
9,9,9
*
```

I would like to save every three lines excluding the asterisk into csv files so my csv files look like this.

0.csv

```
a,b,c
0,0,0
0,0,0
```

1.csv

```
x,y,z
1,1,1
1,1,1
```

2.csv

```
u,v,w
9,9,9
9,9,9
```

Is there any efficient way to do this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to "split" the file into separate groups:

```py
from itertools import groupby

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    i = 0
    for is_asterisk, lines in groupby(f_in, lambda line: line.strip() == "*"):
        if not is_asterisk:
            print("Writing {}.csv".format(i))
            with open("{}.csv".format(i), "w") as f_out:
                f_out.writelines(lines)
            i += 1
```

Prints:

```
Writing 0.csv
Writing 1.csv
Writing 2.csv
```

and saves the files.